# will validate method on InternetAddress object remove the CRLF injection issue

Tags: java, veracode, crlf-vulnerability

I scanned the project with veracode and it is giving issues for CWE ID 93(CRLF injection), This issue is occurring at the bellow line-

```
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(username)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
```

Veracode is flagging the issue 93 at second line from above code.
**username is parsed from request object which is string buffer**

so one of my colleague suggested me that I should use validate method to remove CRLF characters. Will the validate method on address object remove CRLF delimiters ?

Comment: What `validate()` method?

Comment: validate() method is method on InternetAddress Object that can check the correctness of the mail address, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#validate()

Comment: So what happened  when you tried it?

Comment: It will not. validate use to check the address only. It throws "AddressException - if the address isn't valid.".

Answer (score 0):

Use ESAPI(The OWASP Enterprise Security API) . Its totally free.

After setup ESAPI below code will resolve the issue.

ESAPI.encoder().decodeForHTML(username)